# Is a loop needed to set each member of an array of structs to be on the heap?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

My struct declaration:

```
struct tileStruct
{
    SDL_Rect * tilePixel;
    Uint32 * tpColor;
    int * tileNum;
    int * xCoord;
    int * yCoord;
};
```

Here is my function that needs to initialize an array of tileStructs, but each member of the struct is on the heap.

```
void tileInit()
{
    struct tileStruct * tileArr = (struct tileStruct *)malloc(NUM_TILES_IN_WINDOW * sizeof(struct tileStruct)); 

    tileArr->tilePixel = (SDL_Rect *) malloc(tPIXELS_PER_TILE * sizeof(SDL_Rect));   

    tileArr->tpColor = (Uint32 *) malloc(tPIXELS_PER_TILE * sizeof(Uint32));        
    tileArr->xCoord = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));                                   
    tileArr->yCoord = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    tileArr->tileNum = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));

    //rest of function
}
```

So, my question is, do I need to do this?

```
struct tileStruct * tileArr = (struct tileStruct *)malloc(NUM_TILES_IN_WINDOW * sizeof(struct tileStruct)); 

for(int i = 0; i < NUM_TILES_IN_WINDOW; i++)
{
    tileArr[i].tilePixel = (SDL_Rect *) malloc(tPIXELS_PER_TILE * sizeof(SDL_Rect));   

    tileArr[i].tpColor = (Uint32 *) malloc(tPIXELS_PER_TILE * sizeof(Uint32));        
    tileArr[i].xCoord = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));                                   
    tileArr[i].yCoord = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    tileArr[i].tileNum = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Yes, you definitely need the loop for arrays

Comment: You seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of when dynamic memory is appropriate.  Why do you define your struct like this?  Is `tPIXELS_PER_TILE` a constant?  Bear in mind that you're currently initialising the dynamic members, but you're not initialising what they point to.  A more appropriate solution would be to have no dynamic memory in the struct, then allocate and initialise the entire array with one call to `calloc`.

Comment: I know I could just put it all in the stack, but all in all i'm instantiating about 120,000 SDL_Rect structures, so I thought I would just put it on the heap. Yeah, tPIXELS_PER_TILE is a constant I set with #define. It's 256, and NUM_TILES_IN_WINDOW is 475.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use loop. Since you've allocated array of `struct tileStruct` that has `NUM_TILES_IN_WINDOW` elements, you need to iterate through all elements. And your former `tileInit()` initializes only first element.

And probably it would be better to redefine your type in next way:

```
struct tileStruct
{
    SDL_Rect tilePixel[tPIXELS_PER_TILE];
    Uint32 tpColor[tPIXELS_PER_TILE];
    int tileNum;
    int xCoord;
    int yCoord;
};
```

With such definition you can avoid a bunch of auxiliary allocations. (Of course such way is acceptable only when `struct tileStruct` has logical ownership on each of its elements.)